# Sed print the items in square brackets that's after the occurence of a text

Tags: bash, sed

I have the following Scenarios:

- Scenario 1

```
foo_bar = ["123", "456", "789"]
```

- Scenario 2

```
foo_bar = [
    "123", 
    "456", 
    "789"
]
```

- Scenario 3

```
variable "foo_bar" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["123", "456", "789"]
}
```

So i'm trying to figure out how I can print with `sed` the items inside the brackets that are under `foo_bar` accounting `scenario 2` which is a multiline

so the resulting matches here would be

Scenario 1

```
"123", "456", "789"
```

Scenario 2

```
 "123", 
 "456", 
 "789"
```

Scenario 3

```
"123", "456", "789"
```

In the case of

```
not_foo_bar = [
    "123", 
    "456", 
    "789"
]
```

This should **not** match, only match `foo_bar`

This is what I've tried so far

```
sed -e '1,/foo_bar/d' -e '/]/,$d' test.tf
```

And this

```
sed -n 's/.*\foo_bar\(.*\)\].*/\1/p' test.tf
```

Comment: please edit your Q to show what you have tried. Good luck.

Comment: All of this "scenario" are in one file?

Comment: @Jetchisel can possibly happen, ideally i find all occurences of the pattern

Comment: Try to be more specific next time: **I need a POSIX sed solution**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a mouthful, but it’s POSIX `sed` and works.

```
sed -Ene \
'# scenario 1
s/(([^[:alnum:]_]|^)foo_bar[^[:alnum:]_][[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*\[)([^]]+)(\]$)/\3/p

# scenario 2 and 3
 /([^[:alnum:]_]|^)foo_bar[^[:alnum:]_][[:space:]]*=?[[:space:]]*[[{][[:space:]]*$/,/^[]}]$/ {
    //!p
    s/(([^[:alnum:]_]|^)default[^[:alnum:]_][[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*\[)([^]]+)(\]$)/\3/p
}' |

# filter out unwanted lines from scenario 3 ("type =")
sed -n '/^[[:space:]]*"/p'
```

I couldn’t quite get it all in a single `sed`.

The first and last lines of the first `sed` are the same command (using `default` instead of `foobar`).

edit: in case it confuses someone, I left in that last `[[:space:]]*`, in the second really long regex, by mistake. I won’t edit it, but it’s not vital, nor consistent - I didn’t allow for any trailing whitespace in line ends in other patterns.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En '/foo_bar/{:a;/.*\[([^]]*)\].*/!{N;ba};s//\1/p}' file
```

Turn off implicit printing and on extended regexp `-nE`.

Pattern match on `foo_bar`, then gather up line(s) between the next `[` and `]` and print the result.

Comment: `sed: 1: "/foo_bar/{:a;/.*\[([^]] ...": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)`  I'm using MacOSX

Comment: @edmamerto firstly use single quotes not double to enclose the sed commands as shell interpolation may have side effects. Secondly, MacOS uses a form of sed from BSD so perhaps install GNU sed or I believe inserting a`;` before each `}` may help.